# Unable to clone repository from Git

Tags: git, gitlab

I am new to Git. I am trying to clone a repository. I am able to clone it using Git bash command. But when I try to clone it using STS or Source Tree I get an error saying authentication not supported. I tried the following still nothing worked.

1. Created Personal Access Token with api and read_user access.
2. Tried adding `https.sslVerify false`
3. Generated RSA Key from windows-->preferences-->Network
   Connection-->SSH2-->KeyManagement and pasted the public key.

Please guide me further.

Comment: Sometime  Sourcetree gives so many authentication  issue when trying to clone or even take a new pull , just delete the previous stored username and password on sourcetree or maybe this link help you https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-2-1-10-0-Authentication-Issues/qaq-p/623202

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 methods you can try using

1. Try cloning by adding your git username on the clone URL

> git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git

It will prompt you for your password.

Alternatively, you can use

> git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git

Or by using user token in case of Github

> git clone https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git

2. Adding an SSH key on GIT generated from your machine. Use the link shared below to generate one
   https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 1):

**Best approach would be to configure using SSH:**

1. Generate the SSH key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/))
2. Copy the content of your public SSH key, it is the file `id_rsa.pub` by default.

   **Location:** `~/.ssh`(or if you are a window user, it will use whatever $HOME is, i.e., `$HOME/.ssh`)
3. Paste the content into your GitHub/BitBucket account on the SSH key section

**Get the repo**

Just clone it:

**GitHub:** `git clone git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git`

**BitBucket:** `git clone git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git`

Comment: I am able to clone, push, pull using commands. I am trying to do it from IDE which I am not able to do.

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 3.9.3

Answer (score 1):

for clone repository, you can use this command in terminal

git clone https://github.your_project_url.com/project

and when it asks for username and password

user_name: type Github user_name

password: don't use Github password which you use at the time of login to Github, instead, you have to use a personal access token

to generate this personal access token
open your GitHub account and
go to "Settings/Developer settings/Personal access tokens"

thanks

Comment: that worked for me. thanks